# Add Users to ManyToManyField in Model?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Django! so could be way wrong :)

I'm building an event app.
I'm trying to add/remove users to a 'host' list in my 'EventProfile' model from 'MyGuest', i basically want a different host list in each 'EventProfile', i'm using a class method.

I can add/delete each object to each specific EventProfile model in the admin but cant seem to do it on my site?

I keep getting this error "get() returned more than one Host -- it returned 2!"

Heres my code please help :)

Models.py

```
class MyGuest(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='add_myguest', null=True)

@classmethod
def make_myguest(cls, current_user, new_myguest):
    myguest, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(current_user=current_user)
    myguest.users.add(new_myguest)

@classmethod
def lose_myguest(cls, current_user, new_myguest):
    myguest, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(current_user=current_user)
    myguest.users.remove(new_myguest)


class Host(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='add_myguest', null=True)

@classmethod
def make_host(cls, current_user, new_host):
    host, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(current_user=current_user)
    host.users.add(new_host)

@classmethod
def lose_host(cls, current_user, new_host):
    host, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(current_user=current_user)
    host.users.remove(new_host)


class EventProfile(models.Model):
    event = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    greeting = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    invitee = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    finish_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    myguest = models.ForeignKey(MyGuest, related_name='add_myguest_profile', null=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host, related_name='add_host_profile')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.event
```

Views.py

```
def event_change_hosts(request, operation, pk):
    new_host = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Host.make_host(request.user, new_host)
        return redirect('events:event_myguests_profile')
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Host.lose_host(request.user, new_host)
        return redirect('events:event_hosts')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^event_hosts/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.event_hosts, name= 'event_hosts'),
url(r'^connect_hosts/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.event_change_hosts, name= 'event_change_hosts'),
```

template.py

```
{% for host in hosts %}

  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  <a href="{% url 'accounts:profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}" type="button" 
      class="btn btn-primary left"
      class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">{{ host.username }}
  <a href="{% url 'events:event_change_hosts' operation='remove' pk=user.pk %}">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-s">Remove</button>
  </a>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Bootstrap?

Comment: And, nothing to do with the question, but writing everything as classmethods is horrible.

Comment: Prob shouldn't of mentioned Bootstrap i've edited my question

Comment: "And, nothing to do with the question, but writing everything as classmethods is horrible"  Care to elaborate?